# How to parse Fixture Arguments into Java code

Tags: java, fitnesse

In my Fitnesse Test page, I'm trying to define a set of variables in the same row as the Fixture class

```
!|ArgumentsTest|Hello World|Houston We Have a Problem|
```

However, I'm not clear on how to parse `Hello world` and `Houston We Have a Problem` in my Java code.

The [Fitnesse documentation that I'm following](http://www.fitnesse.org/FitNesse.UserGuide.FixtureGallery.ImportantConcepts.FixtureArguments) isn't very clear on how to do this. The `SetFixture` class doesn't have a `doTable(Table arg0)` method that takes in a `Table` object -- only `Parse` objects.

Has anyone had success doing this on their own?

My Java class is very basic with Settings and Getters. The code works just fine if you use a standard Fitnesse table.

Comment: You are using Fit, correct? Why did you tag you question as 'fitnesse-slim'?

Comment: Sorry, I'm quite new to Fitnesse and wasn't sure what kind of structure I was using. I've removed the incorrect tag.

Comment: I recommend using SequenceFixture,see http://www.fitnesse.org/FitNesse.UserGuide.FixtureGallery.FitLibraryFixtures.SequenceFixture.

Answer (score 0):

The sample code is indeed incorrect - it should be `doTable(Parse table)`. But the idea is correct - anywhere in your fixture code, not just in `doTable`,  `args[0]` will be "Hello World", `args[1]` will be "Houston We Have a Problem"